# Bash Script: What does this mean? "done < /dev/null & disown"

Tags: bash, syntax

Can you please explain exactly what the last line of this does, and why it is needed?

```
while true; do
    /usr/bin/ssh -R 55555:localhost:22 -i ~/.ssh/tunnel-id user@server.com
    sleep 1
done < /dev/null & disown
```

That is the entire script, and it's purpose is to create an SSH tunnel to a relay server. I'm new to Bash, but it looks like it will continually try to keep the connection alive, but I don't understand the syntax of the last line.

This script is part of a process to use SSH behind a firewall, or in my case a NAT:
http://martin.piware.de/ssh/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last line redirects `/dev/null` into the loop as input -- which immediately returns `EOF` --  and runs the process in the background.  It then runs a command [disown](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/man/man1/disown.html)(1) in the foreground, which detaches the process, preventing HUP signals from stopping it (sort of like nohup does.).  the effect is to make the loop into something like a daemon process.

The loop overall runs the ssh command once a second.  The command is opening an ssh tunnel, connecting it locally to port 5555 and remotely to port 22 (ssh).  If there is something there to connect, it does; otherwise the redirected EOF causes it to terminate.  It then tries aagain a second later.

(Or so I believe, I haven't actually tried it.)

In bash, disown is a built-in; use `help disown` to see some details.

Comment: How come it outputs "ssh: connect to host server.com port 22: Operation not permitted", but when I comment out the "sleep 1" line it seems to work normally.

Comment: For anyone reading this, it seems to be an issue with Cygwin as this doesn't happen in my Linux distro.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection of `/dev/null` into the `while` loop effectively closes its `stdin` which should be equivalent to `exec <&-`.

Comment: When I run it in Cygwin, it outputs "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." I'm guessing that's normal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a more strange error. If you would to refer the comment I posted on Charlie Martin's answer, I would appreciate it.